# python xgboost DMatrix - get feature values or convert to np.array

Tags: python, machine-learning, eval, xgboost, metric

I'm trying to create custom [evaluation metric (feval)](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.train) function for `xgboost.cv`. It should process some of the training features, however I can't find a way to extract features from [xgboost.DMatrix() object](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.DMatrix) (only labels)..

Or maybe it's possible using callback functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I also want to change metric and I need data from feature, have you solve this problem?